# LCD AMS1117 ceramic capacitors

Tags: capacitor, ldo

I need to use 0603 ceramic capacitors as I do not have enough space on my PCB. Do I need to add small resistance in series (1-2Ohm) as they have a very small ESR comparing to the electrolitic ones? Or it is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times LDO regulators do need some minimum ESR to work properly. Unfortunately the one you are using provides no information regarding this in the datasheet. If you want to play it safe then just put the footprint for an 0603 resistor in series with your capacitors and if you end up not needing it you can install a 0 Ohm resistor. For more info on LDO and ESR here is an appnote from Texas Instruments.

[TI AppNote](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva167a/snva167a.pdf)